# A <canvas> element inside a <div> disappears. What gives?

Tags: jquery-ui, canvas, resize

I've placed a `<canvas>` element inside a `<div>` and it disappears. What gives?

I'd like to to make the canvas element (processing.js) resizable using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that your canvas has no height and the div is collapsing into an invisible horizontal line and is not displaying overflow.  To get a better answer you'd need to post your html.